# How to get the first non comment line number in a file?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a big file that might have some comments in the header

```
# Comment line 1
# Comment line 2
# ...
# Comment line ...
# ...
# Comment line N
123
234
345
...
```

I need a one line solution to get the number "N+1", what's the most elegant way to achieve this using shell script? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this sed one-liner:

```
sed  -n '/^\s*#/!{p;q}' file
```

ok, if you need only the line-number:

```
sed  -n '/^\s*#/!{=;q}' file
```

#### add short explanation:

```
/^\s*#/! : regex, if the line does NOT start with 0 or more empty chars (tab/space)then a '#', the line is chosen for further step.

=  : print line no
q  : quit processing
```

Comment: ... I need its line number

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks! Would you mind explaining it a little bit, so that I could learn how it works? :)

Answer (score 4):

awk version:

```
awk '$1~/^[^#]/{print NR; exit}' file
```